# Change texts "Billing" and "Shipping" in Woocommerce admin order pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, orders

I am trying to change the label text of the "Billing" *("Fatturazione" in Italian)* and "Shipping" *("Spedizion"e in Italian)* in Woocommerce admin Order pages.

See the screenshot below *(related texts are in yellow)*:

[image: Check the attachment for detail]

So for example if I want to change the Billing Address text with "Test"
and Shipping Address text with "Test 2", how could I do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the WordPress `gettext` hook as follows *(targeting non translated original texts)*:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_admin_order_edit_pages_texts', 10, 3 );
function change_admin_order_edit_pages_texts( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {
    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    if( in_array($pagenow, ['post.php', 'post-new.php']) && 'shop_order' === $post_type && is_admin() ) {
        if( 'Billing' === $text ) {
            $translated_text = __('Test 1', $domain); // <== Here the replacement txt
        }

        if( 'Shipping' === $text ) {
            $translated_text = __('Test 2', $domain); // <== Here the replacement txt
        }

    }
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @LoicTheAztec !!!! It works perfectly. I am very happy you solved my issue. Thank you very very much!